# Getting all the values from an array in between a range

Tags: java, arrays

I have a sorted integer array:

```
int[] arr = {13,18,22,29,44,59,77,81,87,99};
```

I want to create a method where i can specify two integers as range **that are not included in the array** and retrieve all the values within the range. Say, 20 to 80. These two values are not in the array. So far, I've tried this, which only works when the two values are present in **arr**:

```
public ArrayList<int> find(num1, num2){
    ArrayList<int> values = new ArrayList<int>();
    int firstIndex = 0;
    int secondIndex = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

        if(num1 == arr[i]){

            firstIndex = i;

        }

        if(num2 == arr[i]){

            secondIndex = i;

        }

    }

    while(firstIndex <= secondIndex){

        values.add(arr[firstIndex]);
        firstIndex++;

    }
    return values;
}
```

Thanks in advance..I'm stuck on this for a while!

Comment: `for(loopOverArray) {if(InRange)add}` as pseudo, pretty much all you need to do. We´re also not here to do the tasks for you, show us your attempt, where you´re stuck and we´ll help. Otherwise you´r question will be closed i´d say.

Comment: *"I'm stuck on this for a while"* Show your attempts, otherwise this sounds like a code writing request. Show what you've done, explain whart part doesn't work, what inputs you're using, etc., etc. People will be happy to help you with why your code isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: My apologies. I've edited the question again. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Loop through your array and check if the number is within the given range (min number for example is nine and max number is 30). Add it to a newly created array then return the array when you're done. I'll provide a code snipit shortly.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> withinRange(int min, int max, int[]array){
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i : array){
        if(i>=min && i<=max){
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

This will include the min and the max in your answer.

Comment: I can't vote you up, since i don't have 15 reputation. Sorry... @MZ4Code

Answer (score -1):

This is one solution:

```
private static int[] valuesBetween(int min, int max) {
    int start = 0;
    while (start < arr.length && arr[start] < min) start++;
    int end = start;
    while (end < arr.length && arr[end] <= max) end++;
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, end);
}
```

You may apply it to an empty array and it works as well if `max` is less than `min`.